# Elasticsearch .net NEST - DeleteByQuery not working but Search for same query works

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to delete some documents from my Elasticsearch collection using NEST

The following code works and returns 3 docs:

```
var results = client.Search<JObject>(s => s.Query(q => q.Terms("string.ProgramId", ids))
```

But when I use same query with DeleteByQuery like this:

```
var response = client.DeleteByQuery<string>(s => s.Query(q => q.Terms("string.ProgramId", ids)));
```

It throws me the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Nest.DispatchException' occurred in Nest.dll

Additional information: Could not dispatch IElasticClient.DeleteByQuery() into any of the following paths: 

 - /{index}/_query
```

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]

Got a response to it at another site that I need to specify indices when using a destructive endpoint such as delete.
And also that I need to specify either the same type in the search/delete for it to go to the same path when querying or specify AllTypes()

Tried the following line:

```
var response = client.DeleteByQuery<JObject>(s => s.AllIndices().Query(q => q.Terms("string.ProgramId", ids)));
```

And though it didn't throw an error this time, it didn't return any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Came to the following conclusion:

You need to have the Search and DeleteByQuery to use the same type if you expect the same results.

Also, the Delete actually happened! but I was expecting response.Found to be true if it deleted anything, which didn't happen.

Should be fixed in NEST 2.0 (they pushed a fix following this issue)

So for now, you can use response.IsValid to validate it came ok (but perhaps not that it deleted anything)